# atomic compare and conditionally subtract if less

Tags: c++, x86, atomic, stdatomic

I manage some memory that is used by concurrent threads, and I have a variable

> unsigned int freeBytes

When I request some memory from a task

> unsigned int bytesNeeded

I must check if

> bytesNeeded<=freeBytes

and if yes keep the old value of freeBytes and subtract atomically from freeBytes bytesNeeded.

Does the atomic library OR the x86 offers such possibilities ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use an atomic compare-and-swap operation. In pseudo-code:

```
do {
    unsigned int n = load(freeBytes);

    if (n < bytesNeeded) { return NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY; }

    unsigned int new_n = n - bytesNeeded;

} while (!compare_and_swap(&freeBytes, n, new_n));
```

With real C++ `<atomic>` variables the actual could would look pretty similar:

```
#include <atomic>

// Global counter for the amount of available bytes
std::atomic<unsigned int> freeBytes;    // global

// attempt to decrement the counter by bytesNeeded; returns whether
// decrementing succeeded.
bool allocate(unsigned int bytesNeeded)
{
    for (unsigned int n = freeBytes.load(); ; )
    {
        if (n < bytesNeeded) { return false; }

        unsigned int new_n = n - bytesNeeded;

        if (freeBytes.compare_exchange_weak(n, new_n)) { return true; }
    }
}
```

(Note that the final `compare_exchange_weak` takes the first argument by reference and *updates* it with the current value of the atomic variable in the event that the exchange fails.)

By contrast, incrementing the value ("deallocate?) can be done with a simple atomic addition (unless you want to check for overflow). This is to some extent symptomatic of lock-free containers: Creating something is relatively easy, assuming infinite resources, but removing requires trying in a loop.

Comment: Thanks a lot !. My problem was that between the load and the exchange the value of freeBytes could had changed, so I cannot trust it, what I didn't realized was that I may prepare the result according to that value and recheck if it has changed before exchanging the values !

Comment: @user3723779: Precisely :-)

Comment: So the above is the solution given the status of technology. But the processor could provide such an atomic operation in one shot !!!

Comment: @user3723779: Yes, it could. But it doesn't.